# Windows 7 kills program for too much memory

Tags: windows, memory, ram

I am trying to 0write the RAM on an 8Gb Windows 7 64-bit machine.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (__int64* i; ; i = new __int64(0))
        continue;

    return 0;
}
```

After it takes up roughly 2-3gigs it throws an exception:  `Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0039f634.`  I can tell there is still plenty of RAM in the task manager though.  I have tried using Visual Studio 2010 and Qt Creator.

Thrown exception breaks in `mlock.c`:

```
void __cdecl _unlock (
        int locknum
        )
{
        /*
         * leave the critical section.
         */
        LeaveCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
}
```

Any ideas?  I want it to write all inactive RAM with 0.

Comment: First:  Memory != RAM.  Second: are you building a 32-bit or a 64-bit binary?

Comment: +1 for 32 bit compilation target - 2GB looks suspicious.

Comment: Yea I figured it was 64 bit already since it was compiling with __int64's.  Got it to work now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile as x64 not win32 in build options